# Spyder failed after Anaconda installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

i,ve tryed to install anaconda on my win10_64 system the hole sunday and lost all time

...
the installation from https://www.continuum.io/downloads#windows works fine...

...after this i click on spyder ide in my win10 startmenue it opened and than...

```
        Spyder updates ...Unable to connect to the internet.
```

right down in the ide on the IPythonconsole reads...

```
        Kernel died, restarting...
```

than i tryd the win cmd and startet an conda update...and it follows...

```
C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod>conda update --all
 Fetching package metadata ...Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
 Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch/
 Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64/
 Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
 Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
 Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
 Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
 An unexpected error has occurred.
 Please consider posting the following information to the
 conda GitHub issue tracker at:

     https://github.com/conda/conda/issues



 Current conda install:

                platform : win-64
           conda version : 4.2.9
        conda is private : False
       conda-env version : 4.2.9
     conda-build version : 2.0.2
          python version : 3.5.2.final.0
        requests version : 2.11.1
        root environment : C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3  (writable)
     default environment : C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3
        envs directories : C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\envs
           package cache : C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\pkgs
            channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
                           https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                           https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
                           https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
                           https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64/
                           https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch/
             config file : None
            offline mode : False



 `$ C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py update --all`




     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 142, in _new_conn
         (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 75, in create_connection
         for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
         for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
     socket.gaierror: [Errno 10109] getaddrinfo failed

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 595, in urlopen
         chunked=chunked)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 352, in _make_request
         self._validate_conn(conn)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 831, in _validate_conn
         conn.connect()
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 254, in connect
         conn = self._new_conn()
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 151, in _new_conn
         self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
     requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000028BDB26BD30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10109] getaddrinfo failed

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 423, in send
         timeout=timeout
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
         release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
         release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
         release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 640, in urlopen
         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 287, in increment
         raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
     requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000028BDB26BD30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10109] getaddrinfo failed',))

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 112, in fetch_repodata
         timeout=(3.05, 60))
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in get
         return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 596, in send
         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 487, in send
         raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
     requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000028BDB26BD30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10109] getaddrinfo failed',))

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 287, in fetch_index
         repodatas = [(u, f.result()) for u, f in zip(urls, futures)]
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 287, in <listcomp>
         repodatas = [(u, f.result()) for u, f in zip(urls, futures)]
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 405, in result
         return self.__get_result()
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 357, in __get_result
         raise self._exception
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 55, in run
         result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 70, in func
         res = f(*args, **kwargs)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 187, in fetch_repodata
         raise CondaRuntimeError(msg)
     conda.exceptions.CondaRuntimeError: Runtime error: Connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000028BDB26BD30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10109] getaddrinfo failed',)): https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/


     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 142, in _new_conn
         (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 75, in create_connection
         for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
         for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
     socket.gaierror: [Errno 10109] getaddrinfo failed

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 595, in urlopen
         chunked=chunked)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 352, in _make_request
         self._validate_conn(conn)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 831, in _validate_conn
         conn.connect()
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 254, in connect
         conn = self._new_conn()
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 151, in _new_conn
         self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
     requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000028BDBAEDD30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10109] getaddrinfo failed

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 423, in send
         timeout=timeout
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
         release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
         release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
         release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 640, in urlopen
         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 287, in increment
         raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
     requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000028BDBAEDD30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10109] getaddrinfo failed',))

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 112, in fetch_repodata
         timeout=(3.05, 60))
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in get

     return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)

       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 596, in send
         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 487, in send
         raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
     requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000028BDBAEDD30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10109] getaddrinfo failed',))

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 473, in conda_exception_handler
         return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 144, in _main
         exit_code = args.func(args, p)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_update.py", line 65, in execute
         install(args, parser, 'update')
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 238, in install
         prefix=prefix)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\api.py", line 24, in get_index
         index = fetch_index(channel_urls, use_cache=use_cache, unknown=unknown)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 293, in fetch_index
         for url in urls]
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 293, in <listcomp>
         for url in urls]
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 70, in func
         res = f(*args, **kwargs)
       File "C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 187, in fetch_repodata
         raise CondaRuntimeError(msg)
     conda.exceptions.CondaRuntimeError: Runtime error: Connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000028BDBAEDD30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10109] getaddrinfo failed',)): https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/



 (C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod\Anaconda3) C:\Users\Matthew MacLeod>
```

has anybody a solution for this ??

...i tried all...searched google and haven't found any logical solution on my self :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:
-Check to see if your internet connection is ok
-Check for the file integrity signature

Answer (score 0):

my connection is ok i checked all

the integrity must be ok it is the installer from anaconda itself and i tried to install ist 10 or 12 times yesterday the hole day... never issues during installation...only firstly when i start spyder

ive postet the same issue on github and there a developer said it could be a problem from there servers

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1220

but today there were the same issues

Comment: EDIT 13:00 o'clock: always the same issue in my IPython Console : `Kernel died, restarting


 
Kernel died, restarting


 
Kernel died, restarting


 
Kernel died, restarting


 
Kernel died, restarting


 
Kernel died, restarting


 
Kernel died, restarting


 
Kernel died, restarting


 
Kernel died, restarting


 
Kernel died, restarting


 
Kernel died, restarting


 ...`